# Best strategy for storing order's addresses

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, rdbms

I have a 'strategy' question.

Thing is, we have a table of customers' addresses and customer orders. Structure is something like (just an example, ignore filed types etc.):

```
Address
id INT
line1 TEXT
line2 TEXT
state TEXT
zip TEXT
countryid INT
```

To preserve historical validity of the data we are storing those addresses in a text field with orders (previously it was done by reference, but this is wrong because if address changes all old orders change delivery address too, which is wrong). E.g:

```
Orders
id INT
productid INT
quantity INT
delivery_address TEXT
```

`delivery address` is something akin to `CONCAT_WS("\n",line1,line2,state,zip,country_name)`

Everything is nice and dandy, however it seems that customers need an access to historical data and be able to export those in XML format and they want to have those lines split up properly again. Because sometimes there is no line2 or state or zip or whatever, how can we store this information in a way that we can then decipher the 'label' of each line?

Storing as JSON encoded array was suggested but is this a best way? I thought about storing it as XML... or maybe create those 6-10 extra columns and store address data with every order? Perhaps some of you guys have more experience in dealing with this kind of stuff and be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would model the addresses as a single table, every update to the address would generate a new row, this would be marked as the current address.

I guess you could allow deletes if there are no related orders, however it would be simpiler to mark the old record as inactive.

This will allow you to preserve the relationship between orders & addresses,
and to easily query the historic data at a later date.

see the wikipedia entry for [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)

Answer (score 2):

The best way IMHO is to add history to the address-table. This will cause extra elements to be added for its key (say address_id and {start_of_validity, end_of_validity}) The customer id than becomes a foreign key into the customer table. The orders table references only the address_id field (which is "stable" in time). New orders would reference the "current" row in address.

NB: I dont know json.

Answer (score 1):

You should store those as 6-10 extra fields, just like you do in the current address. You see, that way you have every piece of information at hand, without having to parse anything.

Any other approach (concatenation, JSON, XML) will make you have to do parsing when you need to access the info.

Answer (score 1):

when you say "previously it was done by reference, but this is wrong because if address changes all old orders change delivery address too, which is wrong", it was not that wrong ...

Funny, isn't it?

So, as proposed by others, adresses should (must?) be stored in an independant table. You'll then have different address types (invoicing, delivery), address status (active, inactive) and a de facto address history log ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to utilize the address data for future uses you will definitely want to retain as much metadata (meaning, fields such as Address, City, State, and ZIP).  Losing this data by pulling it all into a single line looks simpler and may conserve a small amount of space but in the end is not the best method.  In fact, breaking it apart is very difficult--much like separating out first and last names from a generic, one-size-fits-all "name" column.  Having the data stored in complete entries, utilizing 6-10 new fields (as mentioned) is the best way to go.

Even better would be standardizing the addresses (at least the US addresses) when they are first entered.  That would ensure that the address is real and deliverable and eliminate shipping issues in the future.  My thoughts, always retain as much of the data as possible because storage is cheap and data is valuable.

In the interest of full disclosure, I am the founder [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com/).  We provide street address verification.